# Swedish characters, but english captions

Tags: captions, languages, characters

I am writing  thesis in english but I want to be able to use swedish letters. I use

```
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

This works fine, I thought, but I now noticed that all the captions (table, fig etc) use the swedish form "Figur" instead of "Figure" and "Tabell" instead of "Table".
Any ideas on how to achieve the english form of captions and still be able to use swedish letters in the text?

Comment: babel is mainly for changing those texts, the available characters are not changed so you want `[english]` or not babel at all you should still be able to get Swedish characters.

Answer (score 6):

If you write mainly in English and have only certain parts in Swedish (e.g. abstract) you should use

```
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
```

as the last language will be the document default language.

You can now switch languages with

```
{\selectlanguage{swedish}
Denna mening är på svenska. Denna mening "ar p"w svenska.}
```

or

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{swedish}
  Denna mening är på svenska. Denna mening "ar p"w svenska.
\end{otherlanguage}
```

**Note:** With the input encoding `latin1` (or `utf8` for that matter) you are able to directly input ä, Ä, ö, Ö, å and Å. (But you can/should still use `babel` for hyphenation.)

Comment: Yes this works. And just using \usepackage[english]{babel} actually worked    Thank you!

Comment: @AndersKallenberg Sorry for the confusion. Should have read your question more focused. See my updated answer for clarification.